# Android event in Fragment?

Tags: android, events, fragment

Which events are run in Fragment class when I hide tab with this class like this:

```java
    public void onTabChanged(String tag) {
    TabInfo newTab = this.mapTabInfo.get(tag);
    if (mLastTab != newTab) {
        FragmentTransaction ft = this.getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
        if (mLastTab != null) {
            if (mLastTab.fragment != null) {
                **ft.hide(mLastTab.fragment);**
            }
        }
        if (newTab != null) {
            if (newTab.fragment == null) {
                newTab.fragment = Fragment.instantiate(this,
                        newTab.clss.getName(), newTab.args);
                ft.add(R.id.realtabcontent, newTab.fragment, newTab.tag);
            } else {
                **ft.show(newTab.fragment);**
            }
        }

        mLastTab = newTab;
        ft.commit();
        this.getSupportFragmentManager().executePendingTransactions();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you are asking for what callback methods are called when a `Fragment` is hidden using    `FragmentTransaction.hide(mLastTab.fragment)`

The `onPause()` and `onStop()` callback methods will be called when you hide a `Fragment`.

Check [Fragment Lifecycle](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Fragment.html#onPause%28%29)

Comment: thx for answer exactly I asking about "onHiddenChanged()" callback method. By the way sorry for my english ;p